# I get $(image).width() == 0 even when placed inside $(window).load

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, resize, window

I want to resize images that are bigger than the window, but I keep getting 0 width and height when I try to get the image size. I read somewhere that it could be because images aren't necessarily loaded at (document).ready so image functions should go under (window).load, but it's no use. I'm a real newbie when it comes to jquery and javascript so I could be doing something wrong.

This is how my javascript file looks:

```
//<!--
$(document).ready(function(){
    ... 
});

$(window).load(function () {

    $(".lightbox img").each(function() {

        var width = $(this).width();
        var max_width = $(window).width()-30;
        var height = $(this).height();          
        var max_height = $(window).height()-30;

        if(width > max_width || height > max_height) {
            if(height > width) {
                height = max_height;
                width = Math.ceil(width / height * max_height);
            } else {
                width = max_width;
                height = Math.ceil(height / width * max_width);
            }
        }

        $(this).attr("width",width);
        $(this).attr("height",height);

    });
});

//-->
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this in script tags at the top of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this project](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) that provides a callback when images have loaded.

Another reason you could be getting no dimensions is an invisible element (parent or self).

Comment: Yes, it's an invisible element (that it's made visible after an event). I hadn't thought about that though it makes perfect sense. Now I get the size after the element is made visible and it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(this).css("width")` instead of `attr`

Answer (score 0):

When the window loads, the images haven't necessarily loaded yet. JavaScript can't get an image's dimensions until is has *completely* loaded, and until then, you get a computed value of zero.

Bearing this in mind, a repeating loop might help. (Warning: haven't tested)

```
var width = 0;
while (!width) {
    width = $(this).width();
}
```

Watch out for infinite loops, though.

Comment: Would this not actually halt the loading of the image? I really don't advise to use a `while` loop like this. Why not use `$(this).on("load", ...);`? Images also have a `load` event.